# How to restore the default Lubuntu panel in LXDE based Lubuntu releases?

Tags: panel, lubuntu

I accidentally deleted the whole panel.

How can I restore the default panel?

UPDATE: I found a minimized panel on top.

But I have 2 more questions.

1. Now I have a small panel that has a network connection. However, I cannot find `panel settings` when I right click. I'd like to set it to be minimized while not being used.
2. I cannot find `power` (leading to suspend, hibernate, etc ...) in `panel settings`.

Comment: Can you explain "how you accidentally" deleted the panel?

Comment: I was creating new panels and after that tried to delete all but one. I later found the last one on top instead of bottom.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Found this at ubuntuforums.org, hope it helps:

```
cp /usr/share/lxpanel/profile/Lubuntu/panels/panel ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels
lxpanelctl restart
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=c5aa33387123483466eab1a5457ef8ee&p=9557050&postcount=9)

Comment: Actually I tried it before and the 1st and 2nd codes didn't seem to work.

However, I tried the 3rd one now and did work!

Comment: 3rd one alone will restore the default panel but is not enough. If I edit the default panel, it will revert back to it after a while.


Yes, I changed owner:group this time. Let's see if it works.

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly.

Comment: No need to sudo or chmod, at least not in Lubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted my taskbar while trying to remove an app from system tray. This worked for me.

Comment: this works so well! Exactly what i needed

Answer (score 17):

The other answers did not work for me (although to be frank I didn't log out, just `lxpanelctl restart`ed) with Lubuntu 15.04 . This did work for me:

```
$ rm -r ~/.config/lxpanel
$ lxpanelctl restart
```

it may be a bit overkill though.

Comment: This worked for me yesterday on Lubuntu 14.04.03

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04!

Comment: worked like a charm on Lubuntu Server based on Ubuntu 18.04.0 LTS

Comment: @nosmirck: Then express it by upvoting :-)

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, execute the following.

```
cp /usr/share/lxpanel/profile/Lubuntu/panels/panel ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels
```

then logout and login.