# The left side of the lubuntu16.04 screen is covered by many status bar

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu

[SITUATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxOVB.png)

I tried to restart the system and restart Xorg, but they are all in vain. How can I solve this?

Comment: What did you do right before this started  happening?

Comment: Some progresses just crashed and then this happened. Now I've solved this by following this instruction 'https://askubuntu.com/questions/64631/how-to-restore-the-default-lubuntu-panel'