# Reset bottom panel in Lubuntu 20 (restore default)?

Tags: lubuntu, panel, qt

I tried to setup hotspot (and failed, leading to [How can I create a hotspot in Lubuntu 20?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272708/how-can-i-create-a-hotspot-in-lubuntu-20) ), but I managed to somehow delete wifi panel from my bottom panel.

What worse it is not appearing list of available widgets that I can add back.

Not a duplicate of [How to restore the default Lubuntu panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64631/how-to-restore-the-default-lubuntu-panel) as Lubuntu is no longer LXDE based.

Comment: Lubuntu 20?   Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format for all desktop & server releases, and *yy* for all *snap* based releases. Lubuntu being a desktop and being *deb* based is *yy.mm* so please clarify as there is no Lubuntu 20.

Comment: @guiverc My specific version is 20.04.1 LTS but I hope for answer that will stay accurate across all subversions of Lubuntu 20

Comment: Lubuntu won't ever produce a snap based release, we are deb based so will always be yy.mm format, and almost any setting in Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (LXQt 14.1 I think I recall) applies in LXQt 15.0 found in groovy, however a release with the 20 implies it's snap based with Ubuntu's release formatting, which won't apply to a desktop or Lubuntu.

Comment: I'll provide https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html being the manual page for modern Lubuntu (20.04) ;  it won't mention restoration to defaults though. I don't know if restoration is easy, me I'd just add new panel & setup as I wanted, or if needs be copy a ~/.config/lxqt/panel.conf from another system (VM created just to steal it for example) and modify that.  If there's a better way I don't know sorry.  (*mostly copy of IRC reply*)

Comment: In my specific case adding system tray and restarting computer worked. Note that system tray after adding was empty, wifi icon appeared only after restart.